# QT: clicks queuing up during process, while the UI is disabled

Tags: qt, user-interface, c++11

So I have a plugin with lots of buttons and checkboxes. Upon each button click, I disable the UI, there is a long process after which it is enabled again.

The problem is, during this process, if I click anywhere on the UI, eg: a button or check box, it does not react instantly, but as soon as the UI is enabled again, it registers the click that I did about 10 seconds, or even a few minutes ago, and executes it.

I have tried disabling the ui and the buttons

```
widget->setDisabled(true);
```

and also used EventFilter for clicks.

```
bool ShortcutManager::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if (m_isBlocked && (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress
    || event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonDblClick
    || event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease) )
    return true;
//more code...
}
```

Even installed the eventfilter onto the UI

```
sceneLayout->installEventFilter(m_shortcutManager);
m_sceneTree->installEventFilter(m_shortcutManager);
```

But the clicks always seem to get through somehow.

Is there something I am missing?

N.B: Qt 4.6, C++ 11

Thanks

Comment: `Qt 4.6`? You can use `QSignalBlocker` with new versions of Qt from 5.3 and above. Otherwise, [QObject::blockSignals()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#blockSignals) is also an option for you.

Comment: that would be one way of going about it.. but I simply can not block the signals, because the signals and slots are being used during the process.

Comment: It's not like blocking _all_ the signals, you can just block the signals of your UI components and rest will be working fine.

Comment: hmm, let me try that.. thanks